# Drawbacks with embedding event handlers in methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, manualresetevent

Sometimes when I use assemblies that have an asynchronous approach for interaction (you call a method and then you get an event back with the answer) I like to convert them to synchrounus methods by embedding the event handler in the method.

The question is; I don't see this kind of code any where else so I'm getting a nasty feeling that there is some major drawback with this approach that I have missed and that everybody else is seeing. So what do you think - is it ok to write code like this?

Simple example of Logon method that embedds the event handler for the connection event.

```
    private void Logon(GatewayConnection connection)
    {
        const int fiveSecondTimeout = 5000;
        ManualResetEvent waitUntilOnlineEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        EventHandler<ConnectionEventArgs> connectionHandler = (sender, e) =>
                                            {
                                                if (connection.Status == ConnectionStatus.Connected)
                                                    waitUntilOnlineEvent.Set();
                                            };

        connection.ConnectionEvent += connectionHandler;
        connection.Connect();
        bool timeoutReached = !waitUntilOnlineEvent.WaitOne(fiveSecondTimeout);
        connection.ConnectionEvent -= connectionHandler;

        if (timeoutReached)
            throw new ApplicationException("Logon failure");
    }
```

I also think that this type of code, even if the actual method can become a little bit complex, can help in keeping a class that encapsulates a object with a lot of events clean and easy to read.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this approach. Its just some kind of synchronizing an asynchronous method. You could refactor your method so that you can use it with any asnyc method.

Comment: In his book "CLR via C# 3rd Edition" Jeffrey Richter shows an example on how to convert the Event Asynchronous Pattern to a Task. He also shows how to convert the Async Programming Model to a Task. By the way have a look at this article on MSDN comparing ManualResetEvent and ManualResetEventSlim (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbefs30.aspx). If the event is very short then ManualResetEventSlim can perform better. In your specific example it will probably not, though.